# Show that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous in every point a > 0

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing some questions from an analysis list, to present next week. Is my reasoning correct?

Let (x_n) be a sequence of points of $(0, \infty)$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow$ a > 0. We show that $f(x_n) \longrightarrow f(a) = \sqrt{a}$.

Because the convergence of $(x_n)$, given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n > n_0 \Rightarrow \mid x_n - a \mid \ < \ \varepsilon\sqrt{a}.$$

Note that

$$\mid x_n - a \mid \ < \ \varepsilon\sqrt{a} < \varepsilon(\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{a})$$

$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{\mid x_n - a \mid}{(\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{a})} \ = \ \mid \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{a} \mid \ = \ \mid f(x_n) - f(a) \mid \ < \ \varepsilon.$$

Comment: I struggle to see $$\frac{|x_n-a|}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt a}=|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt a|$$

Comment: $(x_n - a)$ = $(\sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{a}) \cdot (\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{a})$. @AndrewZhang

Comment: Oh....yes. Then your work looks good to me

Comment: You need to use the definition of continuity. I expect at your stage you as definition that a function is continuous when the limit coming from below is the same as the limit coming from above. So that is what you need to prove. Your calculations seem correct, you now need to finish the reasoning by saying that both limits are the same because the calculations are valid for both sides.

Answer (score 1):

The way you redacted it would benefit a bit of cleaning.

Also why using a sequence and not just use the definition of continuity ?

This how I would go:

$\forall a>0$ and $|x-a|<\delta$ then $\Big|f(x)-f(a)\Big|=\Big|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}\Big|=\left|\dfrac{x-a}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}\right|$

- For $\delta=\varepsilon$ we have $|x-a|<\varepsilon$
- For $\delta=\frac a2$ we have $|x-a|<\delta\implies x>\frac a2\implies \sqrt{x}>\sqrt{\frac a2}>\frac 12\sqrt{a}$

and $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}>\frac 32\sqrt{a}$

Therefore for $\forall \varepsilon>0$ and $\delta=\min(\varepsilon,\frac a2)$ then $\Big|f(x)-f(a)\Big|<\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{3\sqrt{a}}$

You can eventually refine your delta to arrive to a bare epsilon, but it's not mandatory.

*Note how you needed $a>0$ to be able to squeeze $\frac a2$ and avoid a division by $0$ with the conjugated quantity. For the continuity in $zero$ you'd have to show it separately.*

Comment: Excellent solution! A doubt, you ask about why to use sequences instead of the definition of continuity. Is there any problem using sequences to prove this?

Comment: In a metric space both are actually equivalent, but I think it is more common to use continuity implies sequential continuity than the reverse implication.