# Let $x_n \geq 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that if $x_n \rightarrow x$, then $\sqrt{x_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{x}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to get better at doing these formal limit proofs, but I think that I'm kind of unsure how the AP integrates into these.

I split it into two cases; let's first consider $x=0$. Then, let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary. By AP, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. if $n \in \mathbb{N} \gt N$, then $\vert x_n-0 \vert \lt \epsilon ^2$.

$$\Rightarrow \vert \sqrt{x_n} - 0 \vert \lt \epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{x_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{x} = x = 0$$

Then, when $x \gt 0$. Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary. By AP, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. if $n \in \mathbb{N} \gt N$, then $\vert x_n - x \vert \lt \epsilon \sqrt{x}$. Then,
$$\vert \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x} \vert = \frac{\vert x_n - x \vert}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}} \lt \frac{\vert x_n - x \vert}{\sqrt{x}} \lt \frac{\epsilon \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} = \epsilon$$
Therefore, $x_n \rightarrow x \Rightarrow \sqrt{x_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{x}$.

Is this proof complete? I think I am kind of doing AP incorrectly. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still new to using AP.

Comment: What is the AP?

Comment: The Archimedean principle, I think.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4716319/399263

Comment: @JoseAvilez Archimedean Property

Comment: @zwim we are not allowed to use Delta-Epsilon proofs.

Comment: "we are not allowed to use Delta-Epsilon proofs. "   WHAT?!?!?!  Don't you think that is a rather important detail and needs to be included in your question?   Actually, using AP to do limit proofs is so unusual, I think that it it should be specified that you are specifically looking for an AP proof in the title of the question (and you should not assume anyone knows what the intialims AP means).

Comment: What do your instructors mean when they say that you are not allowed to use $\delta-\epsilon$ proofs? What principles about limits are you allowed to use?

Comment: @fleablood well yes, if I had known what they were before they were recommended by zwim then I would have mentioned it. However, I did not realize that there even was a method to do it with $\delta –\epsilon$ proofs, we just got introduced to doing limit proofs. Sorry

Comment: @RobArthan the post that was linked by zwim uses a proof by showing that the continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ implies that its limit converges. I was simply stating that we aren't allowed to do that (likely because we just haven't learnt it yet, but for my purposes I need a proof using AP).

Comment: Delta epsilons is *the* way to do limit proofs.  To say you aren't allowed to use them is a bit like saying you aren't allowed to use derivatives in a calculus problem.

Comment: The Archimedean Principle says that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}\lt \epsilon$. You are skipping a lot of steps to conclude that given $\epsilon^2\gt 0$ there is an $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $|x_n|\lt\epsilon^2$. You are very implicitly invoking that you "know" that $x_n\to 0$, and this should be done explicitly.

Comment: @fleablood after more practice and viewing of online resources about delta-epsilon proofs, it seems that the confusion was just a result of my professors notation; instead of using $\epsilon$, my professor used $N$, and used $\epsilon$ for $\delta$. I think this was to help students relate it back to the principles of AP. Sorry again for the headache caused.

Answer (score 2):

I am just a student like you so beware with my answer, it seems to me that you are mostly correct. But For myself I will writing the prove as follow.I hope that it will help you.

First let remind that we want to prove that $\forall \epsilon_2 > 0 , \exists N_2>0 : \forall n > N_2 \Rightarrow | \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x} | < \epsilon_2$

1- By assumption $\forall \epsilon_1 > 0 , \exists N_1>0 : \forall n > N_1 \Rightarrow |x_n - x | < \epsilon_1$.

2- Moreover we can note the following inequalities $|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}| = \frac{|x_n-x|}{|\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}|} \leq \frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x}}$ because $|\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}| = \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x} \geq \sqrt{x}$

3- Now according to "1-" for every $\epsilon_1>0$ we can find a $N_1>0$ s.t. $|x_n - x | < \epsilon_1$. If it is true for all type of $\epsilon_1>0$ it is in particular true for $\epsilon_1$ that verify $ 0< \epsilon_1 < \epsilon_2 \sqrt{x}$ no matter what $\epsilon_2>0$ is.

Now let sum up everything.
For all $\epsilon_2>0$ it exists necesarly at least one $ \epsilon_1< \epsilon_2 \sqrt{x} $ and we choose such $\epsilon_1$. Now for such $\epsilon_1>0$ according to "1-" & "3-" $\exists N_1 : \forall n>N_1 \Rightarrow |x_n - x | < \epsilon_1 < \epsilon_2 \sqrt{x} $.
We keep this $N_1$ and we use it to define $N_2$ as follow by setting $N_2=N_1$.
And in such a case we have that (with the help of the inequality in "2-").
$\forall \epsilon_2 > 0 , \exists N_2=N_1>0 : \forall n > N_2 \Rightarrow | \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x} | = \frac{|x_n-x|}{|\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}|} \leq   \frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x}} < \frac{\epsilon_1}{\sqrt{x}} < \frac{\epsilon_2 \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} = \epsilon_2$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can prove the function $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on the interval $(0,+\infty)$.

This implies that it maps convergent sequences onto convergent sequences.

In order to do so, let $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$. Hence one gets:
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| = \frac{|x - a|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}} < \frac{|x - a|}{\sqrt{a}} < \frac{\delta_{\varepsilon}}{\sqrt{a}} = \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Thus for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds $\delta_{\varepsilon} = \varepsilon\sqrt{a}$ such that $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \varepsilon$ when $|x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$.

Hopefully this helps!